# Logistic regression check linearity assumption in R

Tags: r, logistic

How to check the assumption of "linearity of independent variables and log odds" for a logistic regression model in R

- What is the best way to check for the assumption: linearity of independent variables and log odds?
- Which log odds to use? Log odds of the model including all independent variables OR use the log odds of the model that includes only the independent variable you want to check (i.e. separate models for each independent variable)?
- How to determine which polynomial needs to be added to fulfill the linearity assumption?

I created a simple dataset as an example of my real dataset (not possible to include). Note, that the distribution of `age` in this example is different from my real dataset (Don't know how to make the age distribution more realistic).

```
set.seed(1234)
library(ggplot2)

n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(outcome = sample.int(2, n, replace = TRUE)-1,
                  age = sample.int(80, n, replace = TRUE)+20,
                  gender = factor(sample.int(2, n, replace = TRUE)-1,labels=c("M","F")),
                  status = rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 5)
)
```

Fit the full model and check the assumption with a plot. Is this the right way?

```
fit <- glm(outcome ~ age + gender + status, family = "binomial", data = dat)
summary(fit)

plot.dat <- data.frame(logodds = predict(fit, dat), age = dat$age)

ggplot(plot.dat, aes(x=age, y=logodds)) + geom_point()
```

Fit a model with only `age` as a predictor. Is this the right way?

```
fit <- glm(outcome ~ age, family = "binomial", data = dat)
summary(fit)

plot.dat <- data.frame(logodds = predict(fit, dat), age = dat$age)

ggplot(plot.dat, aes(x=age, y=logodds)) + geom_point()
```

Are there other (better) ways to check the linearity assumption in a logistic regression model?

Comment: This is really a question about statistical modeling rather than programming. You'll probably get better results asking over at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: There is a test called Box-Tidwell test which you can use to test linearity between log odds of dependent and the independent variables. Looks like it's implemented in `car` with `boxTidwell()`

Comment: @StatsGuy Thanks. I had a look at the `boxTidwell()` function. But the description states: "Computes the Box-Tidwell power transformations of the predictors in a linear model." I don't see where I can specify the use of a logistic regression model.

Comment: I would guess that you input a linear model of logodds(dep) against the indep variables

Comment: According to John Fox, the author of the `car` package, the `boxTidwell` test is not appropriate for checking the linearity assumption for logistic regression - only for linear regression.